# How to get the in/out packets by ifconfig

Tags: ubuntu, ifconfig

How can I get the in/out bytes separate for ifconfig??

I check packets and bytes by `ifconfig` .

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 153.126.***.**  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 153.126.179.255
    ether 9c:a3:ba:01:df:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 60777328  bytes 18377900528 (18.3 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 33420428  bytes 11013732175 (11.0 GB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I run this script every day and gets byte.

However in this way, in/out packets are mixed.

Is there a way to separate in/out packets??

Or is it impossible for ifconfig (I need to use another tools???)

What I want to do is just get the in/out bytes/packets per day.

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

NIC="ens3"

LOG="/var/log/transmit_bytes.log"

AT=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

TX=`cat /proc/net/dev | grep $NIC | sed -e 's/:/ /' | awk '{print$10}'`

echo "${AT} ${TX}" >> $LOG

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `netstat -ni` to get the packets in an easily-parsable table.

For example, `netstat -ni`

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0      1500  1534430      0      0 0        605131      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536    20701      0      0 0         20701      0      0      0 LRU
tun0      1500   131763      0      0 0        177857      0      0      0 MOPRU
wlan0     1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
```

To pick out the received and transmitted packet count, something like this would be sufficient

```
netstat -ni | awk -v interface="eth0" '$1 == interface { print $3, $7 }'
```

Result

```
1534430 605131
```

For more modern systems with `ip` but without `netstat`, `ip -s -j link show dev eth0` will provide a JSON formatted equivalent

```
[{"ifindex":2,"ifname":"eth0","flags":["BROADCAST","MULTICAST","UP","LOWER_UP"],"mtu":1500,"qdisc":"pfifo_fast","operstate":"UP","linkmode":"DEFAULT","group":"default","txqlen":1000,"link_type":"ether","address":"b8:27:eb:31:53:64","broadcast":"ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff","stats64":{"rx":{"bytes":182767514,"packets":1538635,"errors":0,"dropped":0,"over_errors":0,"multicast":0},"tx":{"bytes":268406197,"packets":606995,"errors":0,"dropped":0,"carrier_errors":0,"collisions":0}}}]
```

This can be parsed with something like `jq`

```
ip -s -j link show dev eth0 | jq '.[].stats64 | ( .rx.packets, .tx.packets )' | xargs
```

Output

```
1538635 606995
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I succeed to use netstat way.